# ls and grep command "not found" error in shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I wonder why "not found" error in my shellscript written in below, so please tell me my mistake in this code.(environment:mac OS X and CentOS6)

"xaf.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER=$1
USER=$2
PASS=$3
FILE=$4
PATH=$5

echo $1
VAR=`ls | grep ${FILE}`

for one_file in ${VAR}; do
    echo $one_file
    echo "go"
    touch ./ftp_err/log

    ftp -nv　2>./ftp_err.log <<END
        open $SERVER
        user $USER $PASS
        cd /$PATH
        binary
        prompt
        put ${one_file}
    exit
END

    VAR2=`wc ./ftp_err.log`
    if [VAR2 -gt 0 ] ; then
        echo "you have an error in sending ${one_file}"
    else
        echo "you have succeeded Transfer of ${one_file}"
        rm ${one_file}
    fi
    rm ./ftp_err.log
done
```

...and command how I issued and the result of execution is as below(part of username and password is replaced by #)

```
**Command**
./xaf.sh 192.168.202.171 #r#####er c#####b## 2 /tmp/

**Result**
./xaf.sh: line 9: ls: command not found
./xaf.sh: line 9: grep: command not found
```

Comment: I succeeded code using ls,grep,and for as written in below

#!/bin/sh

echo $1
FILE=$1
VAR=`ls | grep ${FILE}`

for one_file in ${VAR}; do
echo $one_file
echo "go"
done

Comment: What is the purpose of this: ``VAR=`ls | grep ${FILE}` `` ? Use this instead: `for one_file in *"$file"*; do ...`

Answer (score 13):

Don't do this:

```
PATH=$5
```

`$PATH` is a special variable to the shell. It defines the list of directories to be searched when executing subcommands. If you overwrite that variable, the shell no longer knows where to find subcommands like `ls` or `grep`.

Try giving your variable some other name, like so:

```
xpath=$5
...
cd /$xpath
```

instead.

Generally, avoid using upper-case variable names. The shell uses many different upper-case variable names for its own purposes.

Comment: Yes, but "xpath" has a specific meaning, so using it as a variable name is a little misleading. "path=$5" is fine,

Comment: thanks everyone. finally I get through this error but I found another regarding ftp connection.... I will try to fix it and If i get it I will show you the correct code in this thread.

Comment: @槇大河 That may be because the `ftp` commands are indented. If you use `<<-END`, and use tab characters (not spaces) to indent it, the tabs will be removed before it's passed to the `ftp` command.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER=$1
USER=$2
PASS=$3
FILE=$4
XPATH=$5
LOG='ftp_err.log'


echo $1
VAR=`ls | grep ${FILE}`

for one_file in ${VAR}; do
    echo $one_file
    echo "go"
    touch ${LOG}

    ftp -n 2>${LOG} <<END
        open $SERVER
        user $USER $PASS
        cd /$XPATH
        binary
        prompt
        put ${one_file}
    exit
END
    VAR2=`grep '' ${LOG}|wc -l`
    if [${VAR2} -gt 0 ] ; then
        echo "you have an error in sending ${one_file}"
    else
        rm ${one_file}
    fi
    rm $LOG

done
```

hi everyone.
this works correctly on Linux to Linux.(centos6)

Comment: this code is for ftp and delete files which has been already sent